# About CoreData Saving Different Types of Content

Tags: swiftui, core-data

I have created a simple date app that can record time.
Then I added a navigation bar to it so that each date can record different events.
But I had difficulty in saving these different events. I didn't know what to do

Using conventional saving methods is not feasible, if I create two different dates, then click on the top date, add an event, and save. This way, I can also see the events I saved on the second date, which is terrible!

***Here is the code I provided***

Replication

I've duplicated the issue with the simplest app I can. To duplicate it:

1.Create a new App with Xcode 14.3 clicking the "Use Core Data" flag
2.Change the device type to an iOS (I used: iPhone 14 Pro Max)
3.Replace the datamodel with the following by right clicking on the datamodel file, selecting Show in Finder then right clicking on the file in Finder and selecting Show Package Contents. Repeate for the file inside. Then open the content file, replacing its content with the xml below and saving it. Xcode will automaticlly pick up the change.

```
type here

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<model type="com.apple.IDECoreDataModeler.DataModel" documentVersion="1.0" lastSavedToolsVersion="21754" systemVersion="22C65" minimumToolsVersion="Automatic" sourceLanguage="Swift" userDefinedModelVersionIdentifier="">
    <entity name="Task" representedClassName="Task" syncable="YES" codeGenerationType="class">
        <attribute name="colors" optional="YES" attributeType="String"/>
        <attribute name="deadline" optional="YES" attributeType="Date" usesScalarValueType="NO"/>
        <attribute name="isPinned" optional="YES" attributeType="Boolean" usesScalarValueType="YES"/>
        <attribute name="title" optional="YES" attributeType="String"/>
        <attribute name="type" optional="YES" attributeType="String"/>
    </entity>
</model>
```

4.From the Data Model window run Editor - Create NSManagedObject Subclass...
5.Delete all the files it creates
6.Replace the Persistence.swift file with:

```
//
//  Persistence.swift
//  NewTaskMeage
//
//  Created by sk on 2023/6/7.
//

import Foundation
import CoreData


struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nsError = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
        
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "NewTaskMeage")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
                // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

                /*
                 Typical reasons for an error here include:
                 * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
                 * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
                 * The device is out of space.
                 * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
                 Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
                 */
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        container.viewContext.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
    }
}
```

7.Change the name in quotes on line 33 of Persistence.swift (container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "NewTaskMeage")) back to the name of your container

8.Replace everything in ContentView.swift with:

```
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  NewTaskMeage
//
//  Created by sk on 2023/6/7.
//

import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var shifou = false
    @State private var isPresented = false
    @StateObject var taskModel: TaskViewModel = .init()
    
    //MARK: Matched Geometry Namespace
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: Task.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Task.deadline, ascending: true)], predicate: nil, animation: .easeInOut) var
tasks: FetchedResults<Task>
    @Environment(\.self) var env
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            
            NavigationView{
                
                List{
                    ForEach(tasks) {task in
                        NavigationLink(destination: NoteView()) {
                            TaskRowView(task: task)
                        }
                        
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteTask)
                    
                }
                .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
                .padding(.top,20)
                .navigationBarTitle("Your Time")
                .font(Font.custom("Georgia-Bold", size: 26))
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .toolbar{
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing){
                        Button {
                            taskModel.openEditTask.toggle()
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "plus")
                        }
                        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $taskModel.openEditTask) { //跳转到AddNewTask()
                            taskModel.resetTaskData()
                        } content: {
                            AddNewTask()
                                .environmentObject(taskModel)
                        }
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            
        }
    }
    
    
    private func deleteTask(indexSet: IndexSet) {
        for index in indexSet {
            let itemToDelete = tasks[index]
            
            env.managedObjectContext.delete(itemToDelete)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            do {
                try env.managedObjectContext.save()
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    // MARK: Task Row View
    @ViewBuilder
    func TaskRowView(task: Task) -> some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
            
            HStack{
                Text(task.title ?? "")   //名称
                    .font(.title2.bold())
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .padding(.vertical,10)
                
                Spacer()
                
                
                if (taskModel.daysLeft(for: task.deadline ?? Date())) < 1 {
                    Text("Over")
                        .font(.headline)
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                    
                } else {
                    Text("Remain")
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                
                
                Text("\(taskModel.daysLeft(for: task.deadline ?? Date())) day")
                    .foregroundColor((taskModel.daysLeft(for: task.deadline ?? Date())) < 10 ? .red : .black)
                    .opacity((taskModel.daysLeft(for: task.deadline ?? Date())) < 1 ? 0 : 1)
            }
            HStack(alignment: .bottom, spacing: 0) {
                
                Label{ //日期
                    Text(task.deadline ?? Date(), formatter: dateFormatter)
                   
                    Text(task.deadline ?? Date(), formatter: weekDayFormatter)
                       
                    
                    
                } icon: {
                    Image(systemName: "calendar")
                }
                .font(.caption)
            }
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            
            
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxHeight: 100)
        .background{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12, style: .continuous)
                .fill(Color(task.colors ?? "Green"))
        }
    }
    
    
    
    private let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateStyle = .long
        formatter.timeStyle = .none
        return formatter
    }()
    
    private let weekDayFormatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
        return formatter
    }()
}






struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

9.Replace everything in AddView.swift with:

```
//
//  AddView.swift
//  NewTaskMeage
//
//  Created by sk on 2023/6/7.
//


import SwiftUI

struct AddNewTask: View {
        @EnvironmentObject var taskModel: TaskViewModel
        //MARK: All Environment Values in one Varidable

    @Environment(\.self) var env
    @Namespace var animation
    @State var taskDeadline = Date()
    @State var isPinned = false
    @State var note = ""
    var body: some View {
        
            VStack(spacing: 12){
                
                
                Text("AddTask")
                    .padding(10)
                    .font(.title3.bold())
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .overlay(alignment: .leading) {
                        Button { //退出当前页面
                            env.dismiss()
                        } label: {
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
                                .font(.title3)
                                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                        }
                    }
                
                Divider()
                
                
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
                    Text("Color")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    
                    let colors: [String] = ["Black", "Gard", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Purple", "Red", "Orange","baa","Purples"]
                    
                    HStack(spacing: 15) {
                        ForEach(colors, id: \.self) { color in
                            Circle()
                                .fill(Color(color))
                                .frame(maxWidth: 25)
                                .background{
                                    if taskModel.taskColor == color {
                                        Circle()
                                            .strokeBorder(.gray)
                                            .padding(-2)
                                    }
                                }
                                .contentShape(Circle())
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    taskModel.taskColor = color
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                
                Divider()
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12){
                    Text("Date")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    HStack{
                        DatePicker("", selection: $taskModel.taskDeadline, displayedComponents:[.date])

                        
                        
                        Image(systemName: "calendar")
                            .foregroundColor(.blue)
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                
                
                Divider()
                
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12){
                    Text("title")
                        .font(.caption)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    
                    TextField("", text: $taskModel.taskTitle)
                        .keyboardType(.default)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .padding(.top,8)
                }
                .padding(.top,10)
                
                Divider()
                
                //MARK: Sample Task Types
                
                
                Button{
                    if taskModel.addTask(context: env.managedObjectContext) {
                        env.dismiss()
                    }
                }label:{
                    Text("save")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.callout)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .padding(.vertical,12)
                        .background{
                            Capsule()
                                .fill(.blue)
                        }
                }
                
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
            }.padding(.all,30)
        
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity,alignment: .top)
 
    }
}

struct AddNewTask_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddNewTask()
            .environmentObject(TaskViewModel())
    }
}
```

10.Replace everything in TaskViewModel.swift with:

```
//
//  TaskViewModel.swift
//  NewTaskMeage
//
//  Created by sk on 2023/6/7.
//


import SwiftUI
import CoreData

class TaskViewModel: ObservableObject {
    

    
    @Published var currentTab: String = "Today"
  
    
    //MARK: New Task Properties
    @Published var taskColor: String = "Green"
    @Published var openEditTask: Bool = false
    @Published var taskTitle: String = ""
    @Published var taskDeadline: Date = Date()
    @Published var taskType: String = "Baa"
    @Published var showDatePicker: Bool = false
    
    //MARK: Editing Existing Task Data
    @Published var editTask: Task?
    

    //MARK: Adding Task Core Data
    func addTask(context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Bool{
        // MARK: Updating Existing Data in Core Data
        var task: Task!
        if let editTask = editTask {
            task = editTask
        } else {
            task = Task(context: context)
        }
            task.colors = taskColor
            task.title = taskTitle
            task.deadline = taskDeadline
            task.type = taskType
        if let _ = try? context.save() {
            taskTitle = ""
            return true
        }
            return false
    }

    
    
    //MARK: Reseting Data
    func resetTaskData() {
        taskType = "Baa"
        taskColor = "Yellow"
        taskTitle = ""
        taskDeadline = Date()
    }
    
    
    //MARK: If Edit Task Is Available then Setting Exisiting Data
    func setupTask() {
        if let editTask = editTask{
            taskType = editTask.type ?? "Baa"
            taskTitle = editTask.title ?? ""
            taskDeadline = editTask.deadline ?? Date()
        }
    }
    
     func daysLeft(for date: Date) -> Int {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
         let components = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: Date(), to: date)
        return (components.day ?? 0) + 1
    }

}
```

11.Replace everything in NoteView.swift with:

```
//
//  NoteView.swift
//  NewTaskMeage
//
//  Created by sk on 2023/6/7.
//

import SwiftUI

struct NoteView: View {
    @State private var text = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Form {
                TextEditor(text: $text)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NoteView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NoteView()
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s hard to tell what you’re trying to do, or what problem(s) you are having with it. You say you “had difficulty”. What difficulty? What happened or did not happen that was not what you wanted?

Comment: @汤姆·哈灵顿. Hello, Thank you for your reply. This is a time tool, and the created time information will appear in the list, and we can click to enter this time. I need to save the edited information in this time information when entering. That is to save the information in NoteView.swift